# ngIf on select doesn't display the options at first when set to true

Tags: angular

in my `foo.component.ts`:

```
    numberOfPeople: number = 1
    foo: boolean = false
```

in my `foo.component.html`

```
     <input type="checkbox"
                 name="tst"
                 [(ngModel)]="foo"
                 required>

     <div *ngIf="foo">
        <select [(ngModel)]="numberOfPeople" required>
          <option *ngFor="let n of _.range(1, 11)">
            {{n}}
          </option>
        </select>
      </div>
```

When I set `foo=true` with a click by instance.
At first, I don't see the options, then if I click anywhere on the page, they appear and the option corresponding to my `numberOfPeople` is selected

It seems that the template isn't fully loaded at first, maybe cause I've and `ngFor` inside an `ngIf` ?

**EDIT:**

I have added the missing bit to set the `foo`

Comment: Is the button in the same component?

Comment: It's caused by the code that sets `foo` and perhaps by the way this code is called (or where it is called from)

Comment: How do you set `foo` to true?

Comment: you can use [value] like: <option *ngFor="let n of _.range(1, 11)" [value]="n"> {{n}} </option>

Comment: I have added the edit